# Archimedean completeness of some fields.

Tags: reference-request, nonstandard-analysis, ordered-fields

I need a reference for the following result (different than the Hahn's paper (1907)):

> **Theorem:** If $G$ is an abelian ordered group, then the ordered field $\mathbb{R}((G))$ is archimedean complete.

- $\mathbb{R}((G))$ consists of all the functions $f:G\to\mathbb{R}$ such that 
  $\{g\in G:f(g)\neq0\}$ is well-ordered.
- A field $K$ is Archimedean complete if there is no proper archimean extension of $K$.

Someone knows any good references for the proof of this result? The more the better.

---

**EDIT:**

1. Let $E$ be an ordered field. Two non-zero elements $x,y\in E$ are *comparable* if there are $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x|<m|y|$ and $|y|<n|x|$, where $|a|=\max\{a,-a\}$ for every $a\in E$.
2. Let $E/ K$ be an extension of ordered fields, where the order on $E$ restricted to $K$ coincides with the order of $K$. We say that $E$ is an *Archimedean extension of $K$* if for every $x\in E$, there exists $y\in K$ such that $x$ and $y$ are comparable in $E$.

Comment: Unless $G$ is trivial, $\mathbb{R}((G))$ is not archimedean, so it is archimedean complete...

Comment: I think you are using a different definition of Archimedean completeness. Yes, if $G$ is not trivial, then $\mathbb{R}((G))$ is not Archimedean and also it is archimedean complete. But for example, there are non-Archimedean ordered fields that are not Archimedean complete.

Comment: Consider for example the Levi-Civita field $L(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R})$ of the functions $f:\mathbb{Q}:→\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, the set $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:f(x)\neq0\}\cap(−\infty,n]$ is finite. This is a non-Archimedean field that has $\mathbb{R}((\mathbb{Q}))$ as a proper Archimedean extension, therefore $L(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R})$ is not archimedean complete (see definition of Archimedean extension in edit).

Comment: Okay, this makes more sense. I don't know a reference for a proof, but it follows from Kaplansky's work with maximal valued fields. Are you familiar with the notion of valued fields?

Comment: I am familiarized with valued fields. Can you give me a reference of such Kaplansky's work please?

Comment: "Maximal fields with valuation" by Irving Kaplansky, 1942 in Duke's juornal of mathematics. There is a good survey by I don't remember whom titled "A note on immediate extensions and maximal fields à la Kaplansky". Basically, the idea is that the value group of an archimedean extension of $\mathbb{R}((G))$ with natural valuation is $G$, and the residue field is $\mathbb{R}$, which makes it an immediate extension, and $\mathbb{R}((G))$ being maximal means that it doe not have a proper immediate extension. So what you are looking for is a proof that $\mathbb{R}((G))$ is maximal.

Comment: crosslisted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/253841/archimedean-completeness-of-some-fields

Comment: Just for completion sake, see the link below for more information about the use of the term "non-Archimedean":  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2571362/113061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good reference is pp. 862-863 of Note on Hahn's Theorem on Ordered Abelian Groups, A.H. Clifford, Proc. Am Math. Soc. 5 (1954), pp. 860-863.

See [more references here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253841/archimedean-completeness-of-some-fields)